# How to Automatically Create an Empty Overriding Method for a Base Class's Method, in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

Assume that I created a class that inherits from some base class
(for example, let say I am creating `class AdvancedProgressBar` that inherits `class Control`)
And now I want to inherit **some** of `Control`'s methods.

How can I specifically choose a method in the base class(`Control`), and then tell Visual Studio to create an empty overriding method for it?

Searching with google, I found this tip:

> In the ClassView window, expand the base class under your derived class.
>   Then right-click the desired method, and select Add.

I went to the Class View window, found my class (`AdvancedProgressBar`), expanded the "Base Types" subtree, clicked on `Control`,
and then found some method, for example `OnGotFocus`,
but now when I RightClick `OnGotFocus`, there is no "Add" MenuItem..

[image]

Maybe it's not available in VS2008?
(if indeed it isn't maybe there's another way to do it, in Visual Studio 2008?)

Comment: Who was the nice person who gave me a -1 for this question? I would appreciate a comment regarding why, if anyone thinks that this question is useless for other people, badly asked, does not include preliminary research by the asker, or whatever..

Comment: It wasn't me and I guess it wasn't @Austin either. No one would downvote and then answer the question ... I will upvote and remove negative score.

Comment: Of course, I know it wouldn't be the people who answer.. Thank you two for the answers, I really like VS tips it makes the work faster.. I also upvote any (relevant) answers I receive always - so I upvoted you two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inherit a class, you are forced into inheriting all the `public` and `protected` methods and members. If you're you talking about which ones you can `override`, Visual Studio will tell you with intellisense once you type `override`. It will look something like this:

```
protected override void inherited() => base.inherited();
```

Of course, you can leave out the call to `base.inherited()`, making it an empty, overriding method.

Comment: Hi Austin. Very nice trick. Thank you for it - I will use it from now on. Just out of curiosity, do you know if there's a way to do it via Class View or the Object Browser too? The tip I found via google says yes, tho I do not find how to do it via my VS..

Comment: You're welcome! And the closest thing I found was in the Class View > Sub Class > Base Types > Super Class. Which lists all of the methods and members inherited from the Super Class, which is a start.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from Class View window in VS2008. However, there is another way. For virtual methods, when 
writting code that implements the child class, simply type `override` and then press space. Intellisense  will
show you a list of available methods. Simply select the one you want and a skeleton implementation will be generated.
In case of abstract methods, click on the parent class on the line where you inherit from and a smart tag will appear.
Invoke smart tag menu by either clicking on it or pressing Ctrl+. and you will be given an option to generate skeleton
implementations for abstract methods.

If you are not satisfied with these built-in productivity boosters, you will have to look for some VS extension. An excellent
extension that will enable you to this an much more is Resharper

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

but it is not free so you will have to decide if it is worth it.